# How group the data and get the count each group in excel?

Tags: excel

i have a raw data in excel. i need to group it and get the count in each group. how to get below output in excel

```
colum1    colum2
Dict      34_14234
34562     rtw/453
5535r     rtc/453
453t      rts/53
Dict      34_4524
425q      rfd/532
409q      alf/42
Dict      34/5678
54t      4251/45t
```

```
output
column1         count
Dict 34_14234     3
Dict 34_4524      2
Dict 34/5678      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following formulas:

1. for `Dict` filtering/concatenation:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10 & " " & $B$1:$B$10, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10="dict"),ROW()-1))," ")`

2. for count:

`=IF(LEN(E2)-1,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:$A$11)*($A$1:$A$11&" "&$B$1:$B$11=E3)-ROW($A$1:$A$11)*($A$1:$A$11 & " " & $B$1:$B$11=E2))-1,"")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

[image]

The formula in C2 and D2 respectively:

```
C2 = CONCAT(A2," ",B2)
D2 = COUNTIF($C$2:$C$10,C2)
```

And then if you only want to see the rows that `contain` 'Dict', you can filter on column C (or A) to get that.

Comment: can't sort the data, if sort count will be wrong know

Comment: not if you copy and paste as values, after you get what you need.